# I Hope You Like Connect Walls!

Tags: anagram, connect-wall

Your task?

> Sort the 16 words into 4 groups of 4 words.
>
> Each group will have something in common.
>
> All the common things relate to a tag.
>
> What tag?
>
> ```
>          vexers       flog        angle      sinnet
>
>           mail      solacers     modern       paid
>
>           came      rehandles     pure       serial
>
>          braise      enneads     chokey       sail
> ```

Also, if you have an idea, please post it as a partial answer.

Comment: Can someone help me with the formatting? I've never done a connect-wall puzzle before and it'd be nice to know how to make it better.

Comment: (I have formatted the wall as code with a fixed-width font. I think this is the best you can do with text only. If you think it's uglier than before, roll back.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the groups are:

Group 1: (found by @Mnemonic)

> flog, sinnet, solacers, chokey (anagrams of sports) (golf, tennis, lacrosse, hockey)

Group 2: (found by @Mnemonic)

> mail, pure, serial, braise (anagrams of countries) (Mali, Peru, Israel, Serbia)

Group 3: (found by @Dmihawk, completed by me)

> came, paid, vexers, sail (anagrams of Apple products) (eMac, iPad, Xserve, Lisa)

Group 4: (found by me)

> angle, modern, rehandles, enneads (anagrams of tube stations in London, England) (Angel, Morden, Harlesden, Neasden)

This means that the tag you are referencing is

> anagram

Comment: Well done, this is 100% correct.

Answer (score 9):

Some groups are:

> flog, sinnet, solacers, chokey (anagrams of sports) (golf, tennis, lacrosse, hockey)
>  mail, pure, serial, braise (anagrams of countries) (Mali, Peru, Israel, Serbia)

Comment: This is the closest anyone has got so far.

Comment: rot13(pbhyq gurer or nalguvat gb rznp (pnzr), vcnq (cnvq) naq kfreir (irkref) nyy orvat znqr ol Nccyr?)

Answer (score 6):

Following on from @Mnemonic's answer

> emac (mace), ipad (paid) and xserve (servex) are all made by Apple, the fourth Apple item would be hidden in angle, modern, sail, rehandles or enneads

Comment: (rot13) V guvax vg fubhyq or "fnvy" orpnhfr gurer jnf na Nccyr Qrfxgbc Pbzchgre jvgu anzr "Yvfn"

Answer (score 3):

Partial:

Group 1

> Relating to books and publication
>  1. Solacers (book)
>  2. Enneads (book)
>  3. Serial (def: anything published or broadcast)
>  4.

Group 2

> Relating to crafting/weaving/combining
>  1. sinnet (plaited fiber)
>  2. braise (cooking method that combines dry and wet methods)
>  3. came (slender grooved bar of lead for holding together pieces of glass in windows)
>  4.

Group 3

> Relating to torture or irritation
>  1. chokey (torture cupboard)
>  2. flog (beat with whip/stick)
>  3. vexers (plural of those who irritate, bother, frustrate)
>  4.

Group 4

> Relating to transmission
>  1. mail (send/transmit)
>  2. paid (to settle/transfer/give)
>  3. sail (to move along or travel over water)
>  4. serial (relating to transmission or publication)

Note:

> The duplicates are symptomatic of not knowing the correct groups.

Tag:

> No idea.

Comment: None of these are correct, sorry to burst your bubble.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Saves me time and effort haha.

Comment: You should check out @Mnemonic answer, you may be able to figure it out off that.

Comment: I have been. Their idea is great, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work for some of the other words.